# Div based on selection not working, when new selection line was added

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

i want to create form when there will be possibility to add/remove additional selection rows, but all of this new selection should have possibility to show DIV depends on selected option.

Everything is working fine for first row which is loaded with page, DIV is showing input form, normal text or another selection (this one not need to show anything in additional DIV) based what we choosed.
But for added rows nothing happens after selection.

Any idea how to fix it or use another solution?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div style="width:100%;">
Replace:
        <form>
            <div class="">
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <div id="row">
                        <div class="input-group m-3">
                            <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" name="test" id="type"><option>select one</option><option value="id">ID:</option><option value="client">Client:</option><option value="file">File:</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp; with &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <div id="values"></div>
                            <div class="input-group-prepend" style="margin-left: 20px;">
                                 <button class="btn btn-danger" id="DeleteRow" type="button">
                                     <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
                                     Delete row
                                 </button>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="newinput"></div>
                    <br />
                    <button id="rowAdder" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">
                        <span class="bi bi-plus-square-dotted">
                        </span> ADD row
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

```
 $("#rowAdder").click(function () {
            newRowAdd =
            '<div id="row">' +
            '<div class="input-group m-3">' +
            '<br /><select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" name="test" id="type"><option>select one</option><option value="id">ID:</option><option value="client">Client:</option><option value="file">File:</option></select>' +
            '&nbsp;&nbsp; with &nbsp;&nbsp;' +
            '                <div id="values"></div>' +
            '                <div class="input-group-prepend" style="margin-left: 20px;">' +
            '                     <button class="btn btn-danger"' +
            '                         id="DeleteRow" type="button">' +
            '                         <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>' +
            '                         Delete row'+
            '                     </button> </div>' +
            '</div> </div>';

            $('#newinput').append(newRowAdd);
        });

        $("body").on("click", "#DeleteRow", function () {
            $(this).parents("#row").remove();
        })
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/3th96bac/

Comment: as side note: use backticks which allow you a multi-line string instead of adding multiple strings with a +

Comment: 1 your main problem is your having duplicated id's

Comment: 2 your `$("#type").change(function() {` will not get triggered when new elements are added

Comment: Please modify your HTML and instead of ID please use the class and replace the jQuery with class name in my mentioned example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Please check below working link for your question.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kairavthakar2016/nkrqahpf/11/

**Please modify your HTML and instead of ID please use the class and replace the jQuery with class name in the above mentioned example**

Comment: Problem is still the duplicated id's. Please don't encourage the use of that

Comment: Yes, duplicate ID is the problem here.

Comment: If you know that is the problem, why make an answer that encourage the use of it?

Comment: I have shared comment in the Question area, please check it first

Comment: You shared the comment after you posted the answer. While you answer do "solve" part of the problem, You should also consider informing the OP about the issue in your answer.

Comment: I was typing the comment at that time

Comment: That's my bad, I have updated the answer now. Thanks for highlighting it

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are having multiple elements with the same Id. Id must be unique.

Second you'r `$(".type").change(function() {` will not get triggered by the newly added elements.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on("change", ".type", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == "id") {
      $(this).next(".values").html("<select><option>First option</option><option>Second Option</option></select>");
    } else if (val == "client") {
      $(this).next(".values").html("<input value='Example input' />");

    } else if (val == "file") {
      $(this).next(".values").html("normal text");
    }
  });
});

$("#rowAdder").click(function() {
  newRowAdd =
    '<div class="row">' +
    '<div class="input-group m-3">' +
    '<br /><select class="custom-select custom-select-sm type" name="test" id=""><option>select one</option><option value="id">ID:</option><option value="client">Client:</option><option value="file">File:</option></select>' +
    '&nbsp;&nbsp; with &nbsp;&nbsp;' +
    '                <div class="values"></div>' +
    '                <div class="input-group-prepend" style="margin-left: 20px;">' +
    '                     <button class="btn btn-danger DeleteRow"' +
    '                         id="" type="button">' +
    '                         <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>' +
    '                         Delete row' +
    '                     </button> </div>' +
    '</div> </div>';

  $('#newinput').append(newRowAdd);
});

$("body").on("click", ".DeleteRow", function() {
  $(this).closest(".row").remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div style="width:100%;">
  Replace:
  <form>
    <div class="">
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-group m-3">
            <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm type" name="test" id="">
              <option>select one</option>
              <option value="id">ID:</option>
              <option value="client">Client:</option>
              <option value="file">File:</option>
            </select>&nbsp;&nbsp; with &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <div class="values"></div>
            <div class="input-group-prepend" style="margin-left: 20px;">
              <button class="btn btn-danger DeleteRow" id="" type="button">
                                     <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
                                     Delete row
                                 </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="newinput"></div>
        <br />
        <button id="rowAdder" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">
                        <span class="bi bi-plus-square-dotted">
                        </span> ADD row
                    </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```